# Is there a filtration mechanism that allows nicotine molecules to pass and not particulate matter?

Tags: chemical-engineering, gas, fluid-filtration, vaporization

I was wondering if an equivalent of the vaporization of tobacco could be achieved by normal combustion but passing the smoke through a filtration mechanism that only allows pure nicotine vapor through while blocking particulate matter associated with negative health effects.

I think it could be possible if the nicotine molecule is much smaller than combustion particles like PM25, etc; however, there may be unhealthy gases in the smoke of the burning material such as carbon monoxide. I do not know if there could be a special chemical material which is able to let nicotine through but exclude other gases or molecules.

Comment: `there may be unhealthy gases in the smoke` ... what's healthy about nicotine?

Comment: The obvious answer is do not smoke the nicotine. Take it in through some other way.

Comment: So have you worked out the size of the nicotine molecule? How does it compare to other particles?